# Angular Router when navigating programatically, old component stays in the dom

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-router

Angular version: 4

After signing in from the `LoginComponent` (located in `public/signin` route, I want to navigate to `TestComponent` in the path `public/test`.
I'm doing so as following: `this._router.navigate(['public/test'])`
Then, it redirects correctly but the problem is that it doesn't remove `LoginComponent` from the DOM (although `ngOnDestroy` does get called).

It's worth mentioning that navigating to `TestComonent` using 
`<a routerLink='/public/test'>Test</a>` works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

app.routing.ts:

```
const APP_ROUTES:Routes = [
  {path: 'public', loadChildren: './authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule'}
];

export const APP_ROUTING:ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(
APP_ROUTES, {
useHash: false, enableTracing: true, initialNavigation: true});
```

`
authentication.routing.ts (where both of these components belong):

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {path: 'test', component: TestComponent},
            {path: 'signin', component: LoginComponent},
        ]
    }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Comment: I have the same exact problem, did you figured out how to solve it ?

thx.

Comment: Do you have a normal setup of Angular? Or is it a hybrid application?

Comment: I have a normal setup...

Comment: I had a problem with ui-router while upgrading from ng1..

Answer (score 5):

I have a same problem.
I fixed by add this before routing:

```
this.zone.run(() => {
    // Your router is here
    this._router.navigate(['public/test'])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem as you and found a (temporary) work around.
First i thought it was a routing problem with the lazy loading on a module, i changed to working on the components but the problem never disappeared.

Finally i implemented OnDestroy (from core) in my component.
When the ngOnDestroy function is called i wrote a little javascript that removes the resting element from the DOM.

```
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("parent-name");
var child = document.getElementsByTagName("ng-component");
parent[0].removeChild(child[0]);
```

I know this is just a temporay work around but maybe good enough till you get a final answer from someone one this.

Hope

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Do you have any special configuration to your project or was it a clean angular cli one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a slash to the beginning so that it exactly matches your routerlink?

```
this._router.navigate(['/public/test'])
```

Here is more info on relative vs absolute paths in routes: https://angular.io/guide/router#relative-navigation

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I tried as well `navigateToUrl` and `relativeTo`which didn't work either.

Comment: Can you build a plunker that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I only get this issue when using a hybrid app (ng1 + ng2 app). I'm not really sure of how to upload such an app to plunker. Also, on an ng2 app only, it works as expected. Any ideas?