# Angular Routing issue when navigating programatically, Old component stays in DOM and not destroy

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-module, angular-router-guards

**Duplicate Question:** [Yes. Here it is.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566128/angular-router-when-navigating-programatically-old-component-stays-in-the-dom)

As above question is already asked before but not found any useful answers due to question not properly demonstrates the problem.

**Scenario / Problem:**
I'm using Angular4 and my project is based on Lazy Loading. I've a login page in which I've a button called "Register" when I clicked on my register button it navigate to register module and run its component. The problem which I was facing is when I click on register button my register module loaded properly but my login module not remove from DOM and exists on same page.

Below is the screen shot before I clicked on register button:
[image]

Below is the screen shot after I clicked on register button:
[image]

Below is my folder structure:

[image]

Below is my app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', 
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: AppComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'login', pathMatch: 'full',
        data: { gotoLogin: true },
        canActivate: [ AuthService ],
        loadChildren: './modules/login/login.module#LoginModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'register', pathMatch: 'full',
        data: { gotoRegister: true },
        canActivate: [ AuthService ],
        loadChildren: './modules/register/register.module#RegisterModule'
    }
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        data: { requiresLogin: true },
        canActivate: [ AuthService ],
        loadChildren: './modules/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Below is my login.component.ts:

```
constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder,
    private _Router: Router, 
    private _User: UserService,
    public toastr: ToastsManager, vcr: ViewContainerRef) { 
      this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);
      this.UserForm =  _fb.group({
          "_Username" : ['', Validators.required],
          "_Password" : ['', Validators.required]
    });

    if (this._User.IsUserLoggedIn()) {
        this._Router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    } 
    else {
        this._Router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
}

ngOnInit() {
    if (this._User.IsUserLoggedIn()) {
        console.log('User successfully loggedin.')
        this._Router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }
}

navigate() {
    this._Router.navigate(['/register']);
}
```

Below is my login.component.html:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" (click) = "navigate()">Register</button>
```

Below is my login.router.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', pathMatch: 'full',
        component: LoginComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
],
    declarations: [LoginComponent],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoginRouter { }
```

Below is my app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Below is my app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
title = 'app works!';


constructor(
    private _Router: Router) {
    this._Router.navigate(['/login']);
}

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

I hope I provide brief information regarding my problem. Now what I want is when I click on register button and its navigate to register module then only register module will open and remove all previous modules from DOM.

Comment: try removing `path: ''` from routes at END adding `{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }`

Comment: Is that your only router outlet? And do you see any errors in the console? I assume the register module also has routes?

Comment: @Dhyey from  `app-routing.module.ts` remove path?

Comment: and yes this is my only router outlet. and no errors found in console. Also register has routes same as `login.routes.ts`

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan only the first one, which has `AppComponent` as it's component. Let the other 3 as it is and add the one i recommended with ** at last

Comment: @Dhyey I added `path: '**'` in last of my routes. But the problem still there. when I click on register my register module shows at the top of login module